# Why is alert returning false even when rgb values are equal(considering odd values only)

Tags: javascript, match, alert, rgb

> Click the odd color first time it will be black so from nxt tap its giving the same rgb value but the alert is  returning false on comparison

So basically I want alert to return true for odd colors having same rgb..but it's returning false

[image]

**Here since colors are same and I have clicked on odd number button it should return true but it shows false why so?**

[image]

```js
window.onload = function(){
    
    
var color,num,oddcircle,random_color,r,g,b,odd_color; 
var score = 0;
var circle1 = document.getElementById("component1");

var circle2 = document.getElementById("component2");

var circle3 = document.getElementById("component3");

var circle4 = document.getElementById("component4");

var circle5 = document.getElementById("component5");

var circle6 = document.getElementById("component6");

var circle7 = document.getElementById("component7");

var circle8 = document.getElementById("component8");

var circle9 = document.getElementById("component9");

// adding eventlisteners :)

document.getElementById("component1").addEventListener("click",color1);

document.getElementById("component2").addEventListener("click",color2);

document.getElementById("component3").addEventListener("click",color3);

document.getElementById("component4").addEventListener("click",color4);

document.getElementById("component5").addEventListener("click",color5);

document.getElementById("component6").addEventListener("click",color6);

document.getElementById("component7").addEventListener("click",color7);

document.getElementById("component8").addEventListener("click",color8);

document.getElementById("component9").addEventListener("click",color9);

var ar = [circle1,circle2,circle3,circle4,circle5,circle6,circle7,circle8,circle9]

function update(){
   num = Math.floor(Math.random()*9)
   r = Math.floor(Math.random()*240);
   g = Math.floor(Math.random()*240);
   b = Math.floor(Math.random()*240);
   random_color = "rgb"+"("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
   odd_color = "rgb"+"("+(r+15)+","+(g+15)+","+(b+15)+")";
   oddcircle=ar[num];
   score+=10;
   document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score : "+score;
   oddcircle.style.backgroundColor=odd_color;
   for(i=0;i<=8;i++){
       if(i==num){
           
       }
       else{
          ar[i].style.backgroundColor = random_color; 
       }
   }
}
function color1(){
alert(window.getComputedStyle(circle1).getPropertyValue("background-color") == odd_color+" "+alert(window.getComputedStyle(circle1).getPropertyValue("background-color")+" "+odd_color))
update();
}
function color2(){
alert(window.getComputedStyle(circle2).getPropertyValue("background-color") == odd_color+" "+alert(window.getComputedStyle(circle2).getPropertyValue("background-color")+" "+odd_color))
update();
}
function color3(){
alert(window.getComputedStyle(circle3).getPropertyValue("background-color") == odd_color+" "+alert(window.getComputedStyle(circle3).getPropertyValue("background-color")+" "+odd_color))
update();
}
function color4(){
alert(window.getComputedStyle(circle4).getPropertyValue("background-color") == odd_color+" "+alert(window.getComputedStyle(circle4).getPropertyValue("background-color")+" "+odd_color))
update();
}
function color5(){
alert(window.getComputedStyle(circle5).getPropertyValue("background-color") == odd_color+" "+alert(window.getComputedStyle(circle5).getPropertyValue("background-color")+" "+odd_color))
update();
}
function color6(){
alert(window.getComputedStyle(circle6).getPropertyValue("background-color") == odd_color+" "+alert(window.getComputedStyle(circle6).getPropertyValue("background-color")+" "+odd_color))
update();
}
function color7(){
alert(window.getComputedStyle(circle7).getPropertyValue("background-color") == odd_color+" "+alert(window.getComputedStyle(circle7).getPropertyValue("background-color")+" "+odd_color))
update();
}
function color8(){
alert(window.getComputedStyle(circle8).getPropertyValue("background-color") == odd_color+" "+alert(window.getComputedStyle(circle8).getPropertyValue("background-color")+" "+odd_color))
update();
}
function color9(){
alert(window.getComputedStyle(circle9).getPropertyValue("background-color") == odd_color+" "+alert(window.getComputedStyle(circle9).getPropertyValue("background-color")+" "+odd_color))
update();
}
}
```

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#dadada;
}
#score{
    font-size:25px;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding-bottom:40px;
}
.circle{
    height:calc(100vh/5);
    width:calc(100vh/5);
    background-color:#000;
    border-radius:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}
.game_con{
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    flex-direction:column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="game_con">
    <div id="score">Score : 0</div>
    <div class="comp">
        <div class="circle" id="component1"></div>
        <div class="circle" id="component2"></div>
        <div class="circle" id="component3"></div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="circle" id="component4"></div>
        <div class="circle" id="component5"></div>
        <div class="circle" id="component6"></div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="circle" id="component7"></div>
        <div class="circle" id="component8"></div>
        <div class="circle" id="component9"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*Any help would be appreciated many thanks!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rgb returned when you click on any circle has a white space after every comma

`rgb(156, 233, 40)`

but the odd_color you are creating does not have that white space, Add the white space in your variable you are creating

Just replace

`odd_color = "rgb"+"("+(r+15)+","+(g+15)+","+(b+15)+")";`

By

`odd_color = "rgb"+"("+(r+15)+", "+(g+15)+", "+(b+15)+")";`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion bro..but it's still giving me false for odd values for same same RGB value..it should alert true right?

Comment: yes... it will alert true. please refer here https://jsfiddle.net/f3hb7Lrt/ i have just made some changes in your function and the odd_color